# Find auctions for a user in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm working with L5 and elequent
My table structure is.. 
**users**
id
other field
**auctions**
 id
 other field
**lots**
 id
 auction_id
 other field
**lot_user**
 lot_id
 user_id
I want to find auctions for a user.
How can i do this?

```
$user = User::find($id);
$auctions = $user->auctions();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got an idea to do this with eloquent..

```
    $auctions = $user->lots()
    ->join('auctions','auctions.id','=','lots.id')
    ->select(['auctions.*'])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Eloquent is going to be very efficient here, but you could do something like :

In your User(s) class, you need to define a many-many relationship like :

```
public function lots()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lot');
}
```

In your Lot(s) class, you need to define the inverse of a one-to-many relationship like:

```
public function auctions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Auction')
}
```

Then, to get Lots for a user, you'd do something like :

```
$user->lots();
```

To get auctions, you'd need to loop over lots and call $lot->auctions() for each one, and then filter by id to get the unique auctions.

This is a case where it would probably be easier to use the DB facade to built a query instead of just trying to use Eloquent.

Comment: Auctions does not have a user_id column

Answer (score 0):

About DB facade.
Raw query will looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM auctions AS a
INNER JOIN lots AS l ON (l.auction_id = a.id)
INNER JOIN lot_user AS lu ON (lu.lot_id = l.id AND lu.user_id = $findUserId)
GROUP BY a.id
```

And using query-builder you can do it like this:

```
DB::table('auctions')
    ->join('lots', 'lots.auction_id', '=', 'auctions.id')
    ->join('lot_user', function ($join) {
        $join->on('lot_user.lot_id', '=', 'lots.id')
            ->where('lot_user.user_id', '=', $findUserId);
    })
    ->groupBy('auctions.id')
    ->get();
```